# Derivative of function $A \mapsto \exp(\mbox{trace}(A))$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

> Define $f : M(n \times n,\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ by $$f(A) = e^{\mbox{trace}(A)}$$ Calculate $Df(A)H$, where $H \in M(n \times n, \mathbb R)$.

I'm unsure on what $Df(A)H$ actually means. Is it the Frechet derivative of $f$ at $H$? And, if so, how would I go about calculating that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $Df(A)H$ means the value of the Fréchet derivative of the function $f$ in the point $A$ in the direction $H$, that is, the directional derivative of $f$ in $A$ in the direction $H$:
$$
Df(A)H = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}[f(A+tH)-f(A)].
$$
Define $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
g(t) = f(A+tH) = e^{\mbox{trace}(A)+t\mbox{trace}(H)},
$$
and note that $g'(0)=Df(A)H$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
g'(0) &= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}[f(A+tH) - f(A)]\\
 &= Df(A)H.
\end{align*}
Now,
$$
g'(t) = \mbox{trace}(H)e^{\mbox{trace}(A)+t\mbox{trace}(H)},
$$
thus
$$
Df(A)H = g'(0) = \mbox{trace}(H)e^{\mbox{trace}(A)}
$$

Comment: Why does $g'(0)=Df(A)H$?

Comment: @Loobear23 I added some details.